# Cassandra: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u200e' in position 11141: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: cassandra, cql

I am trying to insert a some huge data through CQL command i am getting `'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u200e' in position 11141: ordinal not in range(128)`

What is this ? How can i detect that character ?

Answer (score 3):

It's rtl mark. Please review this article:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-to-right_mark

To fix it, try to start cqlsh with encoding:

```
cqlsh --encoding utf-8
```

If it doesn't help, please provide more info, about Cassandra version and sample data if possible.

EDIT:
Looks like related:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-10948

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-11626

Is it an option to try executing your load in another version?

Comment: i tried ur solution but no luck. cassandra `2.1.15`